# Grep/Awk: Match shell comments above matched line

Tags: awk, grep

I have a .env file like this:

```
$ cat .env
# My doc for the first var.
FOO_BAR_BAZ1=val1

# My doc for the second var.
# This also spans more than one line.
FOO_BAR_BAZ2=val2

FOO_BAR_BAZ3=val3
```

When I run a command like this:

```
$ grep -i "FOO_[^_]*_BAZ*" .env
```

I want the matched line to be displayed including the lines prior to it that are prefixed with `#`.

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: You can specify `-B 1` or `-A 1` to show one line before and after the match. If you want to make it more exact I guess you would have to use `sed`.

Comment: I did consider the -B and -A option but the number of lines varied. `awk` was the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints only the matching line and the preceding comments:

```
awk '/^#/{c = c $0 "\n"; next} /regex_to_match/{print c $0 "\n"} {c=""}' filename
```

For example:

```
$ awk '/^#/{c = c $0 "\n"; next} /^FOO_[^_]*_BAZ2/{print c $0 "\n"} {c=""}' .env
# My doc for the second var.
# This also spans more than one line.
FOO_BAR_BAZ2=val2
```

or:

```
$ awk '/^#/{c = c $0 "\n"; next} /^FOO_[^_]*_BAZ./{print c $0 "\n"} {c=""}' .env
# My doc for the first var.
FOO_BAR_BAZ1=val1

# My doc for the second var.
# This also spans more than one line.
FOO_BAR_BAZ2=val2

FOO_BAR_BAZ3=val3
```

#### How it works

- `/^#/{c = c $0 "\n"; next}`

  If this line starts with a `#`, then add it to the string variable `c` with a trailing newline.  Then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `/regex_to_match/{print c $0 "\n"}`

  If this line matches the regex, then print comments `c`, the current line `$0`, and, to separate the items an extra newline, `\n`.  If you don't like the extra newline, you can remove it.
- `c=""`

  If we get here, then this line is not another comment line and we therefore reached the end of a comment block.  To prepare for the next comment block, `c` is set to the empty string.

#### Variation

This version is case-insensitive and also allows the regex to be specified on the script's command line:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/sh
awk -v x="$1" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /^#/{c = c $0 "\n"; next} $0 ~ "^Foo_"x"_" {print c $0 "\n"} {c=""}' .env
```

As an example of this script in use:

```
$ sh script 'BA.*'
# My doc for the first var.
FOO_BAR_BAZ1=val1

# My doc for the second var.
# This also spans more than one line.
FOO_BAR_BAZ2=val2

FOO_BAR_BAZ3=val3
```

#### Globs vs regular expressions

Unix has two very different styles for expressing patterns: globs and regular expressions.  With globs for example, `BAZ*` matches `BAZ` followed by zero or more of any other characters.  Awk does not use globs; it uses regex.  In regex, `BAZ*` matches `BA` followed by zero or more `Z` characters.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. Also, thank you for including an explanation.

Comment: I've modified it to accommodate case insensitive matching `awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/^#/{c = c $0 "\n"; next} /^FOO_'"$1"'_/{print c $0} {c=""}' .env`. However, passing an asterisk (like `BA*`) into the script, which is then assigned to `$1`, yields `zsh: no matches found: BA*`.

Comment: @Housni Very good.  I updated the answer with an example of putting the case-insensitive command in a script.  If there are unquoted glob characters on the command line, the shell will try to expand them.  You don't want this.  Put the pattern in single quotes, as shown, so that it gets passed to awk unmolested.  Also, note that awk's patterns are regular expressions, not globs (see updated answer).  Also, using `/^FOO_'"$1"'_/` can be dangerous: it is possible for the contents of `$1` to be interpreted as awk commands with unintended consequences.  The answer shows a safer way of doing this.